# configure: error: Didn't find the MySQL include dir

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, c, mariadb

I am getting an error with configure.

This is the cmd I am running `./configure --with-mysql-lib=/lib64  --with-ev-lib=/usr/lib64`

**The full error:**

> checking for MySQL include directory... no
> configure: error: Didn't find the MySQL include dir in '/usr/include/mysql /usr/local/include/mysql /usr/local/mysql/include /usr/local/mysql/include/mysql /usr/mysql/include/mysql /opt/mysql/include/mysql /sw/include/mysql'

> Os: centos 8
> database : maraidb 10.4

**Installed packages:** Am I missing something?

```
MariaDB-common.x86_64                         10.4.12-1.el8                                  @mariadb
MariaDB-shared.x86_64                         10.4.13-1.el8                                  @mariadb
mariadb.x86_64                                3:10.3.17-1.module_el8.1.0+257+48736ea6        @AppStream
mariadb-backup.x86_64                         3:10.3.17-1.module_el8.1.0+257+48736ea6        @AppStream
mariadb-common.x86_64                         3:10.3.17-1.module_el8.1.0+257+48736ea6        @AppStream
mariadb-errmsg.x86_64                         3:10.3.17-1.module_el8.1.0+257+48736ea6        @AppStream
mariadb-gssapi-server.x86_64                  3:10.3.17-1.module_el8.1.0+257+48736ea6        @AppStream
mariadb-server.x86_64                         3:10.3.17-1.module_el8.1.0+257+48736ea6        @AppStream
mariadb-server-utils.x86_64                   3:10.3.17-1.module_el8.1.0+257+48736ea6        @AppStream
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it turns out that mysql++ 3.2+ was need i had 3.1 installed